# Cannot print/log message in Spark API

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, logging, rdd

I'm debugging a Spark job, but somehow, anything inside a Spark API call is hidding from the console/logs, here's my code:

```
public static JavaRDD<SolrInputDocument> join(
        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRdd,
        List<NuggetsField> fields) {
        System.out.println("In join method....");
        logger.error("In join method.... logger.error");

        JavaRDD<ProductJoin> pjs =  hBaseRdd.map(tuple -> {
            System.out.println("in map API .....");
            logger.error("in map API.... logger.error");
            /**do some transformation*/
        });

        System.out.println("got ProductJoin RDD.....");
        System.out.println("pjs.count() = " + pjs.count());
        return pjs;
  }
```

`In join method....` and `In join method.... logger.error` and `got ProductJoin RDD.....` and `pjs.count() =` could always print out.

However, `in map API .....` and `in map API.... logger.error` are never shown.

Why is this?
Also, `pjs.count()` value is not 0.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check using `yarn logs -applicationId application_id`.

Comment: I tried that before, but I got `-bash: yarn: command not found`, :(

Comment: OK, I was able to do so, but still in this yarn log, there's still nothing logged. what could go wrong?

Comment: what mode you are running spark application?

Comment: --master yarn       --deploy-mode client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is what JVM runs the print line because that is the log on which it will appear.
In your case since you are running on yarn except the driver, you can see the printout of the driver but not of any code that runs on executors (like the map).
That output goes into the corresponding yarn container stderr file.

If you want to see any print statement while you are debugging the easiest thing is to run in local mode.

About pjs.count(), the map operations makes 1 to 1 convertions, it cannot remove elements. You would need to apply a filter later to remove nulls.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code when **join** method is executed whatever the System output messages mentioned in the method will be printed on the **driver** side from where you are submitting the spark-submit job. But in case of **pjs** it's a RDD and will be evaluated only when action will be called on it here it will get executed when **pjs.count()** is called and this will be evaluated at **Executor** side. So whatever Sysout messages you mention in the transformations that will be printed at Executor side. To access these logs you need to access the YARN container logs through **yarn logs -applicationId application_id** as the logs from the executors will be aggregated in containers . As I see you are getting yarn command not found then please add "$YARN_HOME/bin" to your CLASSPATH and try the command.

Please use following link:- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

**Section:** Debugging your application